# c++ Pipe Redirection with CreateProcess() issues

Tags: c++, pipe, remote-access, readfile, createprocess

I'm attempting to make a remote administrator tool, so I can control my home computer, and I have the server working. I can send commands across the network fine, but I'm having trouble executing them in the cmd. I have tried to use the CreateProcess() function to start the cmd and then write commands through a pipe, and read the result. I would like to do this multiple times without closing the cmd, so that I can use cd, etc.

It seems like it is at least partially working because it prints out the welcome message for the cmd when the startCmd() function is called. After this however, when I try to write commands to the cmd it never gives me any output. When I check the out pipe, it says that it has read 0 bytes, except when it first starts.

Does this mean that I can only execute 1 command, or do I need to manipulate the pipes in some way after using them once, or something else like that? Also, I apologize if the code is sloppy, I have just been trying a bunch of different solutions and I havent been worrying about the cleanliness of my code.

```
#define BUFSIZE 4096
#define PATHMAX 400

bool running = false;

HANDLE hChildStdInR = NULL;
HANDLE hChildStdInW = NULL;
HANDLE hChildStdOutR = NULL;
HANDLE hChildStdOutW = NULL;

PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;

void ErrorExit(const char*);

bool startCmd()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStdOutR, &hChildStdOutW, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit("StdoutRd CreatePipe");

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hChildStdOutR, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit("Stdout SetHandleInformation");

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 
    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStdInR, &hChildStdInW, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit("Stdin CreatePipe");

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hChildStdInW, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit("Stdin SetHandleInformation");

    char cmdPath[PATHMAX];
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 
    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.
    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = hChildStdOutW;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = hChildStdOutW;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = hChildStdInR;
    siStartInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    GetEnvironmentVariableA("ComSpec", cmdPath, sizeof(cmdPath));

    // Create the child process. 
    bSuccess = CreateProcess(
        cmdPath,
        NULL,     // command line (NULL because application itsself is cmd)
        NULL,          // process security attributes 
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,             // creation flags 
        NULL,          // use parent's environment 
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION

    // Close un-needed pipes
    /*CloseHandle(hChildStdOutW);
    CloseHandle(hChildStdInR);*/    // Doesn't change anything why I uncomment these lines

    // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
    if (!bSuccess)
        ErrorExit("CreateProcess");
    else
    {
        // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread. Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status of the child process, for example. 
        /*CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);*/
    }

    return true;
}

bool writeToCmd(const string& s)
{
    DWORD dwWritten;
    const char* cmd = s.c_str();
    return WriteFile(hChildStdInW, cmd, sizeof(cmd), &dwWritten, NULL);
}

bool exec(const string& command)
{
    if (!writeToCmd(command)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Succesfully Wrote" << endl;
    }
    return true;
}

void checkPipe()
{
    while (running) {
        while (1) {
            Sleep(50);
            DWORD bytesAvail = 0;
            if (!PeekNamedPipe(hChildStdOutR, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytesAvail, NULL)) {
                cout << "Failed to call PeekNamedPipe" << endl;
            }
            if (bytesAvail) {
                CHAR buf[BUFSIZE];
                DWORD n;
                BOOL success = ReadFile(hChildStdOutR, buf, BUFSIZE, &n, NULL);
                if (!success || n == 0) {
                    cout << "Failed to call ReadFile" << endl;
                    break;
                }
                string s = string(buf, buf + n);
                cout << s << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <ADRESS>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ClientSocket client(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT);

    // Wait for initial response
    string w = client.recieveLine();

    if (w == "welcome") {
        cout << "Connection Successful! " << endl;
    }

    running = true;

    if (startCmd()) cout << "Cmd Started" << endl;
    thread checkLoop(&checkPipe);

    while (true) {
        vector<string> command = split(client.recieveLine());
        if (command[0] == "run") {
            exec(command[1]);
        }
        else if (command[0] == "exit") {
            running = false;
            client.sendLine("exit");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!CloseHandle(hChildStdInW))
        ErrorExit("StdInWr CloseHandle");

    checkLoop.join();
    client.close();

    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```